# What is the diode used for in this circuit?

Tags: diodes, schematics

In this schematic (it is of a board from Adafruit, I included the link below) what is the diode's purpose?  Originally, I thought it was to only allow for an logic signal from the Reset Pin, but then, wouldn't the diode be placed in the opposite direction?  I am not really an Electrical Engineer, just curious.

Thanks.

Full Schematic:

https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/024/546/original/sensors_BNO055_REV-C.png?1429569060

Image:

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first thought is correct.

- If RST_5V is left floating, R10 will pull NRESET_3V up to 3.3v.
- If RST_5V is driven low, current will flow through the diode and NRESET_3V will be pulled to ground

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Quick follow up: what do you mean by "floating"?

Comment: Not actively driven

Comment: Ok, what if the input is driven high, what would be the effect? (last question, I promise :) )

Comment: No worries! I'm here to slack :)

If the input is driven high, no current will flow through the diode. High is sort of a default state, so there's no need to actively drive that line